# Using Pagination with Categories

Tags: categories, pagination

Is there a way to paginate a list of categories? For example, I have 9 categories and would like to display 3 categories with their description on each page. It seems like it should be as easy as the following, but no luck.

```
{exp:channel:categories limit="3" paginate="bottom"}
    <a href="{path='channel/index'}">{category_name}</a>
    {if category_description}{category_description}{/if}
 {paginate}
        {if previous_page}
            <a href="{auto_path}">Previous Page</a> &nbsp;
        {/if}
        {if next_page}
            <a href="{auto_path}">Next Page</a>
        {/if}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Comment: Hi Lou, I am not aware of a pagination-specific solution for your situation, but checkout this plugin https://github.com/t1mwillis/GWCode-EE3-EE4-EE5. It will give you super powers with categories and you might be able to create a solution that essentially gives you the option you are looking for.